# Twig - print array without empty values

Tags: php, loops, twig

I have array constructed like this

```
add_to_context('custom', [
  [
   'title' => 'My title',
   'link' => 'My link'
  ],
  [
    'title' => 'My title 1',
    'link' => 'My link 1'
  ]
]);
```

and in view I have simple loop

```
{% for item in custom %}
    <li>
        <h1>{{ item.title }}
        <img src="{{ item.link|e }}" target="_blank">

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And everything works fine. But I want to print elements which have both keys with value. For example, if I have

```
[
  'title' => '',
  'link' => 'mylink'
]
```

I don't want to print this. If link will be empty I don't want it too. If both are empty - the same. I want to print it only if both keys have values. So, how can I do this?

Comment: Twig can check if a value is empty. See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/empty.html). All you need after that is a simple `if`.

Comment: So I need to check if my 'item' is empty inside for loop but before printing <li> element, right?

Comment: Your item will still have content in the example you showed us. It's the 'item.title' you want to check.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Something along the lines of `{% if item.title is not empty && item.link is not empty %} ...`. Ofc if you want more validation you can also check if [defined](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html), although it's not really necessary if you're absolutely sure that the values exist.

Comment: @Andrei So, I changed your && to or, so I have now `item.title is not empty or item.link is not empty` when title is empty and link have value `<li>` element still shows up but with empty title. What I want to not show all li element when title or link is empty. Or both are empty

Comment: According to your initial question u'd want `and`'s not `or`'s

Comment: @DarkBee when I use `and` and one value is empty my whole list don't shows up :/

Comment: @DarkBee, Andrei ahhh, my mistake. I have typo error. Now it works like it should. Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this, maybe.

Twig even has a little built in functionality for this:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in custom if item.title and item.link %}
        <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I haven't tested it, but I assume the `and` in the `if` statement should work.

Comment: This doesn't work. Twig error: `Unexpected token "name" of value "if" ("end of statement block" expected).`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a simple test in your template :

```
{% for item in custom %}
  {% if item.title|length %}
      <li>
          <h1>{{ item.title}}
          <img src="{{ item.link|e }}" target="_blank">

      </li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Generally speaking ,  **"0"|trim** expression will evaluates to false.